# Alt key not recognized - Dell Inspiron n4110/Mint 16 (Petra)

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I'm running a fresh install of Mint 16 on an essentially-brand-new Dell Inspiron N4110. I booted to Kali Linux initially, and noticed <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F4</kbd>, and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> (address bar focus) weren't working in Iceweasel, which I dismissed as a minor glitch or a missing driver or something. After downloading & installing Mint, the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key still does not work. `xev` shows absolutely nothing during an <kbd>Alt</kbd> keypress (<kbd>LAlt</kbd> or <kbd>RAlt</kbd>).

I've never had this problem before, and Google isn't turning up much. Has anyone else seen this, or have an idea of where to look? As far as I can tell, the rest of the keys are working fine, and the Fn key is in "normal" mode (<kbd>F12</kbd> = <kbd>F12</kbd>, as opposed to <kbd>F12</kbd> = <kbd>Mute</kbd>).

Comment: Sounds like you selected an incorrect keyboard layout during installation. Can you confirm that you're using a 105 key board layout?

Comment: I re-saved the US keyboard setting (couldn't find more specific on Mint) and rebooted, and now it works. I'll dig up the other settings change later, in case it works for someone else.

Comment: great news. Yes please take the time to write up an A w/ screenshots if possible so that others can learn from your experience.